# Strange characters in .NET core with ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core

my application is written in Spanish and I get strange simbols when I use special characters like: "´","ñ" and "¿". 
Here you can see better:
[image: strange simbol]

Instead it should say: "Breve descripción".
I already set the meta tag with the UTF-8 attribute in my _Layout.cshtml
.I'm using dotnet core 1.0.4 ASP MVC

Some help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us how you write the symbols in the razor view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the default .cshtml files from MVC. Then, you have to edit the file by changing the format to UTF-8.

Comment: What do you mean with default?

Comment: Your default .cshtml file should be here: C:\Users\USERNAME.nuget\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc\VersionNumber\Templates\ViewGenerator\

Comment: I haven't found "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.‌​CodeGenerators.Mvc"

Comment: @Lucas David Ferrero Hmmm, then try saving your _Layout.cshtml file with encoding UTF-8. Go to "Save As" and in the window that opens up, go down to the encoding field and select UTF-8.